# Using rspec to test Perl?

Tags: ruby, perl, rspec, tdd

Ok, this may sound insane, but can rspec be used to test perl classes? The reason I want to is because were I work all production code must be Perl. But I am learning ruby and will eventually leave perl behind.

I'm aware of Test::Expectation, a perl testing framework based on rspec.

But sadly, we don't do test first development. I would like to do that everyday, but using rspec.

Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run Perl code from Ruby so yes, it's possible, but:

1. All your tests will look like "When I run some Perl code I expect this result"
2. You will not be able to use most of the rspec features.
3. You will have to do a lot of hacking for no good reason.
4. If you're trying to learn rspec, you won't (this way).
5. No one sane will reuse or expand your tests.
6. Even if you switch to Ruby you'll have to rewrite all your tests.

If you feel like your development workflow could be improved talk to your boss / lead developer / responsible person and suggest using test tools that are native to Perl. These guerilla tactics like "I'll do it my way because I know better" can easily get you into trouble.

P.S. I'm only trying to be helpful, please don't feel like I'm being condescending or mocking your idea.

Comment: No no, I understand completely. That is very helpful. Sadly we don't have a 'Lead Developer' and my boss is simply not interested in making any kind of improvement to the way software is developed :(

Comment: I'm just trying to do everything I can to re-skill myself, ready for a new job

Comment: I've been in a similar situation before - tried to implement TDD and failed miserably (I ended up being the only one testing my code, failing tests in production for months and no one cared, etc.) All I can say is good luck job hunting :)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like you know exactly where I'm at!